# Preventing router navigation in case of an effect failure/error

Tags: redux, rxjs, rxjs5, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am migrating to use **ngrx Effects** and I have the following issue: since `dispatch` returns `void` I am not sure how prevent router navigation if an error occurs from my ngrx effect (e.g. from `this.userAccountService.updateFirstName(...`).

From my component class:

```js
  updateFirstName() {
    this.formStatus.submitted = true;
    if (this.formStatus.form.valid) {
      //Dispatch from the store
      this.store.dispatch(new UpdateFirstNameAction(this.formStatus.form.value.firstName));
      //Undesired behavior: will navigate even in case of error/failure!
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/useraccount']);
    }
  }
```

From my effect class:

```js
  @Effect()
  updateFirstName$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(currentUserAccount.ActionTypes.UPDATE_FIRST_NAME)
    .map((action: UpdateFirstNameAction) => action.payload)
    .switchMap(firstName =>
      this.userAccountService
        .updateFirstName(firstName)
        .map(() => new UpdateFirstNameSuccessAction(firstName))
        //I obviously can't navigate from here
    );
```

I am not sure it is a good practice (or even possible) to use the router in order to navigate from the effect.

Can someone please suggest a clean solution to prevent the router navigation in case of an error occurring from my effect?

Comment: UpdateFirstNameSuccessAction should setFirstNameSuccess = true,
then when you subscribe to it, get the value and if so, redirect to your page.

Comment: Hi @ShlomiLevi, then I would be introducing new state. Wouldn't I?

Comment: in nutshell, you should react to store changes. :)
it's not necessary to have a new state, just build your state to support the field that changed.
This is because your store should have the state, and when you dispatch an action, you basically change the store. so after you change the store, you subscribe to the field that changed and because of that, you react with what ever you want :)

Comment: How do I subscribe to the field? Can you quote the API methods? Can I avoid introducing a boolean of all of my fields?

Comment: it's not be a boolean, it's just value changed. when it's changed you do whatevent you want.. see my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the [`@ngrx/router-store`](https://github.com/ngrx/router-store) module. With it you can create routing actions and, using it, you have a few options.

You can emit multiple actions from a single effect. So your effect could use `concatMap` to emit two actions: your success action and a routing action (created with the [`go`](https://github.com/ngrx/router-store#navigation-with-a-new-state-into-history) action creator):

```js
import { go } from '@ngrx/router-store';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/concatMap';

@Effect()
updateFirstName$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType(currentUserAccount.ActionTypes.UPDATE_FIRST_NAME)
  .map((action: UpdateFirstNameAction) => action.payload)
  .switchMap(firstName => this.userAccountService
    .updateFirstName(firstName)
    .concatMap(() => [
      new UpdateFirstNameSuccessAction(firstName),
      go(['/dashboard/useraccount'])
    ])
  );
```

However, you might also want to consider using a separate effect that manages only the routing:

```js
import { go } from '@ngrx/router-store';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mapTo';

@Effect()
updateFirstRouting$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType(currentUserAccount.ActionTypes.UPDATE_FIRST_NAME_SUCCESS)
  .mapTo(go(['/dashboard/useraccount']);
```

Another thing to consider is that a single effect can respond to multiple actions, so you could use a table of simple action-type-to-route mappings to do something like this:

```js
import { go } from '@ngrx/router-store';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

simpleRoutes: { [type: string]: string } = {
  [currentUserAccount.ActionTypes.UPDATE_FIRST_NAME_SUCCESS]: '/dashboard/useraccount'
};

@Effect()
simpleRouting$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .map((action) => this.simpleRoutes[action.type])
  .filter(Boolean)
  .map((route) => go([route]));
```

Whichever option you choose, using routing actions for navigation that is initiated within effects makes things more easily testable. It's easy to write effect tests to ensure that when an effect receives a particular action, it emits the appropriate action. There is more information on testing effects [here](https://github.com/ngrx/effects/blob/master/docs/testing.md).

Comment: Thanks a lot Cartant. I like better the separate effect that manages only the routing. I still have one interrogation: does this solution introduces coupling between the `ActionTypes.UPDATE_FIRST_NAME_SUCCESS` and the routing? Is there a way to avoid this coupling?

Comment: If you always want an action to navigate to a particular route, I cannot see how coupling would be a problem. It sounds like you have a situation in which you might or might not want to navigate. I've updated the answer with another option. Note that it could be extended to use a dynamic table that could be configured via the service that hold the effects. So you could set up the action-to-route mapping before dispatching the UPDATE_FIRST_NAME_SUCCESS action. Maybe something like that is closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. The last solution is nice and flexible.

Comment: This is an interesting suggestion.  I'm curious to hear how @cartant would handle authenticating into a system and being redirected to a dashboard.  If the user hits the back button, it's desirable for the user to stay on the home screen, since they are authenticated.  The way I've been doing it is checking if the user is authorized in the OnInit of the `LoginComponent`.  But, perhaps a routing guard is more suitable?

Comment: @cgatian Yep. You should use guards for that sort of thing. The mechanisms mentioned in this answer are just for navigating in response to effected actions; they don't replace any of the more traditional routing mechanisms or infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it one of two ways.

1. With an Effect, catch the SUCCESS action and then redirect:

   ```
   @Effect() someeffect$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
       .ofType(currentUserAccount.ActionTypes.UPDATE_FIRST_NAME_SUCCESS)                
       .do(action => /* do redirect (action.payload) */);
   ```
2. With Subscribe:

   Let's say this is your state:

   ```
   {
       account: {
           username: null
       }
   }
   ```

   Component:

   ```
   var username$ = this.store.select(account => account.username);

   username$.subscribe(user => {
       // the user have changed due to reducer who is getting the action with new user.
       // do here redirect...
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just another question though: is there any reason why you `subscribe` from the store instead of  `select` from it? Also is it good practice to navigate from en effect and not from a component?

Comment: you welcome. Yes, you should use `select`. because it's get you the slice from the Store. It's just quick and dirty answer.. ;) 
It's better to redirect from effects because it's your BL. I mean you can apply or remove effect for your choice. in some cases you do redirect and another cases you do something else. so all you have to do apply/remove effect dynamic.